# How to create a custom class in NestJS and work with the instance of the class

Tags: class, nestjs

I'm trying to create a helper class in NestJS which i can use in every file.
I tried to create the following class:

```
export class Logging {
  public status: string;
  private currentLog: Model<LogDocument>;

  constructor(@InjectModel(Log.name) readonly log?: Model<LogDocument>) {
    // Create a new log item when new instance of class is created
    this.currentLog = new this.log({
      title: 'New Log',
      status: SyncStatusType.IN_PROGRESS,
      startTime: new Date(),
    });
  }

  public addCrashLog() {
    // Update current log
  }

  public addSuccessLog() {
    // Update current log
  }

  public finish() {
    // Set status and update log
  }
}
```

I want to be able to use this class in every other file and create a new instance of the class if necessary.

```
const newLog = new Logging();
newLog.addCrashLog();
....
```

Does someone have an idea how I can archive that with NestJS? Because I'm always having problems with dependency injection in NestJS when I'm trying to create a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't add the `Logging` class to **any** `providers` array, as that's what will tell Nest to create the instance. Next, if you're passing the values yourself, you don't need the `@InjectModel()` there's no need, as you're creating the class yourself. Lastly, just use the class as your example already shows, using the `new` keyword and handling the instantiation yourself. That should be all there is to it

Comment: How can I use the defined LogSchema in the Logging class without passing it every time in the constructor when not using @InjectModel ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You want to handle instantiating the class, but you don't want to have to pass in the schema each time?

Comment: What I basically trying to archive is that I have a class which handels the logging for me. Every time I create a new instance of the "Logging" class, I want to create a new log item in my database. Then, the class instance holds my created mongoose log item and I can add "addCrashLog", "addSuccessLog", via the Logging instance. In a normal node project I can just import the mongoose schema in the class and work with it but I'm not sure how I can do that in NestJS

Comment: If you want to be the one to call `new` on the `Logging` instance you have to pass all the appropriate values to the constructor. You can do this in the constructor of the class that's going to have the `Logging` instance if you want. Otherwise, you could make a `LoggingModule` that creates the `Logging` provider, exports it, and then make use of that provider in other services.

Comment: „Otherwise, you could make a LoggingModule that creates the Logging provider, exports it, and then make use of that provider in other services“
@JayMcDoniel
I'm not sure if I understood that correctly. Could you explain it with an example?